# why am I getting heap buffer-overflow when use c++ STL sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

Following is my custom compare function:

```
static bool compare(int x, int y) {
    string _x = to_string(x);
    string _y = to_string(y);
    return _x + _y >= _y + _x;
}
```

And I coding like this:

```
vector<int> nums(10000, 0);
sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), compare);
```

Running, I will get a error:

```
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address on ...
```

I think it was my compare function that caused this problem, but I don't know how to solve.

Comment: can this ever be false? `return _x + _y >= _y + _x;`

Comment: Compare functions for sorting must enforce strict weak ordering. If compare(x, y) is true, then compare(x, y) must be false. When x and y are equal integers, this requirement is violated.

Comment: After you solved the compare, also imagine what would happen if you have negative integers. What are you trying to do with your compare?

Comment: @artm If `_x == "0"` and `y == "1"`

Comment: Also, the strict weak ordering is also violated if one number is the other number repeated as a string (e.g., `compare(1, 11) && compare(11, 1)` and `compare(37, 3737) && compare(3737, 37)` are both true)

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yes, I found this rule on the cpprefrence.com.  But I also want to know what causes heap overflow.

Comment: @artm Yes, when I changed it to `return _x + _y > _y + _x',  it's ok.

Comment: Now I know how to solve, can someone tell the reason of heap overflow?

Comment: If your comparison function does not enforce a strict weak ordering, the results of calling `std::sort` are undefined.   "Undefined behavior" covers pretty much *anything*.

Comment: FWIW, the answer to "why does `std::sort` do something bad" is **always** because it was called with a custom comparator that doesn't satisfy the comparator requirements. Don't have to see the code; it's in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you violate the [compare requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) that the comparison function passed to std::sort is required to follow.

The compare requirement requires that If `comp(a,b)==true` then `comp(b,a)==false` and `comp(a,a)==false` but your comparison function does not do this.

The comparision should be

```
return _x + _y > _y + _x;
```

instead of

```
return _x + _y >= _y + _x;
```

You need to return false when `_x + _y ==_y + _x` and you don't do that.